# Coordinates convertion with QGIS

Tags: coordinates, qgis, wgs84

i'm trying to convert coordinates from Monte Mario italy 1 (EPSG 3003) to WGS84 (EPSG 4326). These coordinates are contained in a csv file. To do that i'm using QGIS (2.0.1 dufour). So i open the file opening "layer" menu and i select "Add delimited text layer". Then i open the file specifying the source and QGIS autodetects the columns which contain the coordinates. After this i specify the coordinatea format as EPSG 3003. QGIS open the layer perfectly. Then i try to save the file as "delimited text" specifying that i want it in EPSD 4326 format. The output file is just the same as the input one. What's wrong ?

Comment: Answered on GIS Stackexchange [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49351/export-to-new-projection-in-qgis-1-8).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to repoject your data via GDAL_transform in the console:

Create a shape file within qGIS and then reproject from -s_srs "EPSG:3003" -t_srs "EPSG:4326".

Answer (score 0):

Actually i solved this. I start creating a SHP file from the file in format CSV. This can be done by the ogr2ogr. Still using ogr2ogr by the shell i used the command `ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:3003 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f CSV [Dest file].csv [Source file].shp -lco GEOMETRY=AS_YX`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and  I don't Why QGIS works like that.

The QGIS does convert from one coordinate to the other. Instead of reading the CSV file, try reading the shape  files. Generally, the shape files contain more  information than any other files..It is easy to read a shape file using java or python.

Follow the below steps,

1. Read the shape file
2. Save it as a text file
3. Convert it to the required format you want